# Set operations on classes of functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-set-theory

Set operations on classes of functions?

E.g. what does $C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ mean?

Is $C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})=C^1(\Omega)$

since $\Omega \cap \bar{\Omega}=\Omega$ and $C^2 \cap C^1$ is intuitively $C^1$, because $C^1 \subset C^2$.

Comment: What does the $C^n$ operator do? If it's common notation, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @StefanMesken https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness

Comment: Also particularly here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Order_of_continuity it's seen that $C^2$ contains $C^1$.

Comment: Oh, that's what you were talking about. Turns out I was familiar with the notation but couldn't glance the appropriate context from your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an example that applies enough contrast to focus on the important distinction...

- Let $C^4((1,5))$ be the set of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that are $4$ times continuously differentiable on $(1,5)$.
- Let $C^6((3,7))$ be the set of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that are $6$ times continuously differentiable on $(3,7)$.
- What is $C^4((1,5))\cap C^6((3,7))$?

The answer is the same as any set intersection. $A\cap B$ is the set of things that are in both $A$ and $B$. So $C^4((1,5))\cap C^6((3,7))$ is the set of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that are $4$ times continuously differentiable on $(1,5)$ **and** $6$ times continuously differentiable on $(3,7)$.

It is **not** equal to $C^4((3,5))$. You can't just "distribute" the $\cap$ into both the function class and the domain. There's no principled reason to do that. We do have $$C^4((1,5))\cap C^6((3,7))\subset C^4((1,5))\subset C^4((3,5))$$
and $$C^4((1,5))\cap C^6((3,7))\subset C^6((3,7))\subset C^6((3,5))\subset C^4((3,5)),$$
but the reverse inclusion fails quite badly. Instead,
$$C^4((3,5))\not\subset C^4((1,5))$$
and
$$C^4((3,5))\not\subset C^6((3,7))$$
and so
$$C^4((3,5))\not\subset C^4((1,5))\cap C^6((3,7)).$$

Now, I made certain to specify that all of my spaces consist of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, and that simple setting was enough to make my main point. But your original example of $C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ has an additional complication. A priori, we might define $C^2(\Omega)$ as a set of functions $\Omega\to\mathbb R$, and $C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ as a set of functions $\bar{\Omega}\to\mathbb R$. Given such definitions, if we are being pedantic, these two sets have empty intersection!

But obviously, someone who writes $C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ is not intending to write down the empty set in a roundabout way. Instead, they mean to *identify* any smooth-enough function $\bar{\Omega}\to\mathbb R$ with its restriction $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. And once you do that, these sets have a meaningful intersection, and you get the answers of Lucas Galhego and Fred: $C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ is the set of functions that obey both a $C^2$ condition on $\Omega$ and a $C^1$ condition on $\bar\Omega$.

Also, regarding this claim:

> $C^2 \cap C^1$ is intuitively $C^1$, because $C^1 \subset C^2$.

Actually, it's the opposite. Over some fixed domain, we have $C^2\subset C^1$. A function in $C^2$ is certainly in $C^1$, but the reverse is generally false. So $C^2 \cap C^1= C^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$ f \in  C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ means: $f \in C^1(\Omega)$ and each partial derivative of $f$ has a continuous contnuation on $ \bar{\Omega}$.

Hence $f \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ means: $f \in C^2(\Omega)$ and each partial derivative of $f$ of order $1$ has a continuous contnuation on $ \bar{\Omega}$.

Answer (score 1):

$C^{2}(\Omega)\cap C^{1}(\overline{\Omega}) \neq C^{1}(\Omega).$

$C^{2}(\Omega)$ is the space of all two times differentiable functions,
$$f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
 with continuos derivatives.

And $C^{2}(\overline{\Omega})$ is the space of all two times differentiable functions,
$$f:\overline{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
 with continuous derivatives.

You can see $C^{2}(\Omega)\cap C^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$ as all $C^{2}$ functions in $\Omega$ with a $C^{1}$ extension in $\partial \Omega.$